# Deserializing derived classes with Jackson

Tags: java, inheritance, jackson, deserialization

I have two auto-generated classes as follows:

```
public class DataMonitoringClauseType extends ClauseType {
}

public class ClauseType {
}
```

As the classes are autogenerated I cannot define additional annotations like `JsonSubType` for them.

I have a third object with a list of ClauseTypes as follows:

```
public class RootClass {
    List<ClauseType> clauses;
}
```

Given a serialized `RootClass`, is there a way to deserialize the `RootClass` instance such that I would have `DataMonitoringClauseType` instances inside the `clauses` list?

I already tried registering the derived class as follows with no success:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerSubtypes(DataMonitoringClauseType.class);
```

Note that the serialized content is passed as an input to the server. Therefore, I don't have the chance to include type information in the serialized content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Jackson you can define a custom deserializer for `ClauseType` along the lines of

```
class ClauseTypeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<DataMonitoringClauseType> {

    @Override
    public DataMonitoringClauseType deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        // get data, e.g.: data = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp).toString().getBytes();
        // construct result:
        return new DataMonitoringClauseType(data)
    }
}
```

You can make it more generic declaring to return `ClauseType` and then making a decision which instance to return based on data. Either way, register it with the `ObjectMapper` using:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
  .registerModule(new SimpleModule()
    .addDeserializer(ClauseType.class, new ClauseTypeDeserializer()));
```

If you are ever interested in Gson, the solution is very similar:

```
class ClauseTypeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ClauseType> {

    @Override
    public ClauseType deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        // get data, e.g.: data = jpson.toString().getBytes();
        // construct result:
        return new DataMonitoringClauseType(data)
    }
}
```

And register it with the `GsonBuilder`:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
  .registerTypeAdapter(ClauseType.class, new ClauseTypeDeserializer())
  .build();
```

Comment: Puzzled about down votes without a comment as I can actually provide a github link to both above examples used in production code for exactly the problem inquestion. Anyway, some people are strange and that's a fact of life

Comment: Thanks Oleg! I was just trying the same solution without knowing how to access the 'data'. Now, I got it and it works!

Comment: I think writing custom (de)serializers is a wasteful approach in case where there are literal one line solutions. I would recommend against doing that, unless there is no other approach.

Comment: @StaxMan Now if you said use type adapter factory to map one type into another without writing a customer deserialiser I would agree even though the answer above is generic. If your suggestion is to use annotations I strongly disagree: my DTO module should neither have a dependency on a particular serialisation (annotation) library nor the DTO should actually know how it will be used.

Comment: @OlegSklyar directly adding annotations is one method -- and you are free to dislike that part, some developers do, others don't, and it's a valid discussion. But that is not the only way. I do realize that you were not aware of the alternatives, and in that sense your suggestion is a valid solution. As to DTOs not having to know, that... is part of bigger discussion and depends on context.

Answer (score 1):

Use of custom deserializer is not needed 
No need for custom deserializers or Gson. Jackson offers couple of ways.

First: just because you can not directly modify classes does not mean you could not use Jackson annotations: this is the exact use case for "mix-in" annotations. See https://dzone.com/articles/jackson-mix-in-annotations for example on how to use mix-ins, so you can have equivalent of

```
@JsonDeserialize(as=DataMonitoringClauseType.class)
public class ClauseType { .... }
```

Alternatively you can also register implementation type (your attempt at registering subtypes would work for polymorphic subtypes, where type id is used -- but I don't think that's what you want here).
That is done using `Module` interface, method "addAbstractTypeMapping()"

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleModule.html#addAbstractTypeMapping-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-

Comment: IMO use of custom deserializers is much cleaner because your DTO is then decoupled from the serialization technique. I know some like annotations, which does not make them any better.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't want to add additional classes as we have already a large data model. However, I was seeking something like the second alternative. I'll try it out.

Comment: @OlegSklyar tastes vary, sure, but to me having to write custom (de)serializer seems like lots of work to get result that typically is inferior to handlers that library provides, and is often more fragile as well. It is basically just more code you have to support. Annotations are also more along functional approach where one indicates what should happen instead of writing imperative code. And your comment on "some like annotations" seems to suggest you have emotional dislike of annotations, more so than rational reasoning.

Comment: @StaxMan There are a few nearly philosophical questions and differences in approach here and SO is not really a good place to discuss them :) I neither like nor dislike annotations and I see nothing functional about them really. But I do dislike misuse of annotations to solve any possible problem at hand (think EE, JPA, Servlets etc.). As for JSON serialisation so far I managed to solve all the problems without annotations with minimum overhead and I've solved a lot of those by now.

Comment: @OlegSklyar agreed wrt philosophy/design, and that this is not a good forum (nor is there real answer necessary). I agree that annotations may be overused, and also that there are trade-offs esp. in case of linkage in "wrong direction" (like potentially here). I'll leave it at that, except to note that my second suggestion is no-annotation one, and I probably should have mentioned that that is my number one suggestion, and NOT the annotation. Appreciate the discussion here as it's analytic & rational; apologies if I misrepresented your views.

Comment: @StaxMan would be a nice feature to have on SO to automatically continue in some dedicated discussion room. I find these sort of exchanges very valuable for getting better insights. Thanks to you as well!